# Every open subset $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a union of open intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

***The Theorem:***

Every open subset $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a union of open intervals.

***The problem asks for a particular method of proof:***

"Complete the proof by showing that $O = \displaystyle\bigcup_{x \in O} (x - r_x, x + r_x)$."

***My work:***

By the definition of open, we know that, for all $x \in O$, there exists an $r_x > 0$ such that $(x - r_x, x + r_x) \in O$. Since this is true of all $x \in O$, then $O$ precisely is the union of all such intervals. Thus, we have $O = \displaystyle\bigcup_{x \in O} (x - r_x, x + r_x)$.

***My question:***

Does this work? The result seemed obvious and the proof trivial - enough so to make me nervous and think I must have begged a question somewhere.

Comment: This is fine. The result is indeed obvious because the proof is trivial.

Comment: This indeed works

Comment: You have shown that $\cup_{x\in O} (x-x_r,x+x_r) \subset O$ but not that $O=\cup_{x\in O} (x-x_r,x+x_r)$.  But as $x\in (x-r_x,x+r_x)$ we know that $O=\cup_{x\in O}\{ x\} \subset \cup_{x\in O} (x-x_r,x+x_r)$ this is ... still trivial.   Not so trivial will be to show That $O$ is a *countable* union of intervals.  But the question didn't ask for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Possibly a typo, but it should be $(x-r_x,x+r_x) \subseteq O$ where you have written $\in$
2. Formally, your argument as written should only conclude $\bigcup_{x\in O} (x-r_x,x+r_x) \subseteq O.$  A simple argument [that you should include] shows the other inclusion.